# Error statement on Django and Python web development

Tags: python, html, django, html-table

I've one problem here on elif statement.

time and visual are my checkbox value.[Click here for more understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRZQt.png)

**On if statement is working if user select visual in checkbox it will display the output that I read from text file.**

**When comes to elif statement if check only time it will display nothing**

**I want user to have an option want to display the first statement, second statement or both of it**

> THIS **views.py**

```
    token = request.GET.get('token')
    context = {}
    data = {}
    prev_key = ''
    with open(path) as input_data:
            for line in input_data:

                if (token == 'visual'):
                    if line.startswith('2_visualid_')
                         prev_key = line.lstrip('2_visualid_').rstrip()
                         data.update({line.lstrip('2_visualid_').rstrip(): []})

                elif (token == 'time'):
                   if search_string in line:

                         if prev_key in data:

                         data[prev_key].append
                           (next(input_data).lstrip('2_mrslt_').rstrip())

             context = {'output': data}

             return render(request, 'Output.html', context)
```

> Form HTML

```
<form action="">

    &nbsp&nbsp<input class="regular-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="token" value="visual"><b>&nbsp&nbsp Visual ID</b><br>
    &nbsp&nbsp<input class="regular-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="token" value="time"><b>&nbsp&nbsp Time Delay Index</b>

 </form>
```

> **Note**

*Hope you can understand be pleased to comment on my explanation don't just downvote it because I learn nothing from it. Thank you.*

Comment: I haven't downvoted, but it is unclear what exactly you ask. In any case, you have a typo in your code: `if search_string in line` is missing a `:`

Comment: Yaa, sorry it because of copy paste missing the double colon. I will edit to make it clear. I'm sorry. Maybe I need to straight to the point.

Comment: For help with bugs, create a [mcve].

Comment: Okay done :D I make it simple

Comment: Please post your form's  html code.

Comment: Done posted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok your problem is that 1. you're only retrieving one single value for the `token` key (HTTP querystrings and forms can have multiple values for a same key) and 2. you're only testing against one single value.

The first problem is easily solved by using `request.GET.getlist("token")` to get all values (instead of only the last one), [as documented here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects).

The second problem is easily solved too: now that you have a list instead of a single value, just test for containmenent (`if xxx in values`) instead of equality (`if value == xxx`) and replace the `elif` with a `if`:

```
tokens = request.GET.getlist('token')
# ...
with open(path) as input_data:
    for line in input_data:
        if 'visual' in tokens and line.startswith('2_visualid_'):
            prev_key = line.lstrip('2_visualid_').rstrip()
            data.update({prevkey: []})
            # you may want to continue to next line here - or not
            # continue

        if 'time' in tokens:
            if search_string in line and prev_key in data:            
                 data[prev_key].append(next(input_data).lstrip('2_mrslt_').rstrip())
```

Comment: Thanks, Bruno, that was great. Now I able to display the visual id or both visual id and time delay. But still, I cannot display only time index without visual id. It will show nothing. I really appreciate your answer. Because I just learn Python by self-learning for this 1 month. That's why it's difficult for me to find the solution even it is easily solved...

Comment: If you read your code and think about what each line do, you should be able to find out why you get nothing without the "visual" token. Hint: check how you use `prev_key` in both branches...

Comment: I get nothing because of prev_key return nothing and  is not in data.  but I have tried to change it else  if search_string in line and prev_key not in data: data.update(next(input_data).lstrip('2_mrslt_').rstrip()), but it still show nothing.

Comment: This is my code, it works but on my visual id column has one single cell that displays the time result. but others work fine it shows in time column...  CODE:  on below of my question, call update.